# Using external handlebars templates with Marionette in Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: handlebars.js, marionette

Is it possible to reference external Handlebars template files without using Marionette.Async?

I just want to better organize my template snippets (Rails Asset Pipeline), so asynchronous loading isn't required but individual files are. Are there any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the wiki lists a plugin that makes it easy to work with Handlebars, and a simple way to make handlebars work with out any plugins.

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-handlebars-templates-with-marionette

https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars

these might do what you need. if not, it would be a good place to start, to get the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help and such a great Backbone Plugin. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that Handlebars already works with Marionette (and that I've read the wiki, your great blog posts and so on). My only problem is that I have to include the script tags in my main template which is confusing if you have many of them.

Comment: Do you think I should use Rails erb-templates to outsource the template snippets in folders of my choice and don't depend on asynchronous loading or other javascript ways?

Oh, and why do you prefer underscore templates? I'm new to Backbone and Handlebars so any advice is welcome.

Comment: async template loading is a last resort when you have too many templates (more than a few hundred KBytes, maybe). using ERB w/ rails to build templates is one option, but it would be better to use JST and pre-compile your templates with the rails asset pipeline. https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-jst-templates-with-marionette

Comment: i prefer underscore templates because it comes with backbone for free. it's a simple default that anyone using backbone can take advantage of. but i know others don't want to use it, so marionette makes it easy to change. i also like handlebars, and have seen a number of other template engines supported. i don't think there's a right or wrong choice for template engine. it's a matter of preference and performance.